# Not receiving GET response from Express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, get

When I send a GET req from my client to my Express server it sends the data to the client but I get an XMLHttpRequest ready state of 1 and a status of 0 and it never logs the response text.

Client:

```
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
  console.log(this.readyState);
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      console.log(this.responseText);
  }
};
req.open('GET', url + 'users', true);
req.send();
```

Server:

```
app.get('/users', function(req, res) {
  res.send(users);
});
```

If anyone can tell me why I can't receive the array of users on client side and how to fix it. That would be great.

Comment: make sure you use relative path in req.open..anyhow it should be url+"/users"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would use `fetch` javascript because it looks more natural.

```
/* on server */
app.get('/users', function(req, res) {
  res.send(users);
});


/* on client */
fetch('/users').then(async (response) => {
  if (response.status === 200) {
    console.log(await response.text());
    // do you receive something ?
  }
  else {
    throw new Error('something unexpected occurred');
  }
}.catch(err => { console.err(err) })
```

If you don't receive anything, then you should check if your front page is served from the same data-providing server because when you call for `/users` the browser is prepending the host to the path. So if both your client page and your back server is not running on the same host it will fail.